# if conditional for background color?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert, background-color, tic-tac-toe

I've been trying to make a tic-tac-toe game but for some reason, the conditional isn't working..

I tried to target the first three elements on the first row and if they all were the same color, I wanted to browser to alert a "win" pop-up, but it doesn't happen.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Here's my code:

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var three = document.getElementById("three");
var four = document.getElementById("four");
var five = document.getElementById("five");
var six = document.getElementById("six");
var seven = document.getElementById("seven");
var eight = document.getElementById("eight");
var nine = document.getElementById("nine");


var counter = 1;

//code that changes the box color
one.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    one.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    one.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
two.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    two.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    two.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
three.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    three.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    three.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
four.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    four.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    four.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
five.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    five.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    five.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
six.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    six.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    six.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
seven.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    seven.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    seven.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
eight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    eight.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    eight.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
nine.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 === 0) {
    nine.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else if (counter < 10 && counter % 2 != 0) {
    nine.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});

//logic for winning
if (one.style.backgroundColor == "red" && two.style.backgroundColor == "red" && three.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
  console.log("red wins");
}
```

```css
.knobs {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.knobs:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#total {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div id="total">
  <button id="one" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="two" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="three" class="knobs"></button>
  <br>
  <button id="four" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="five" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="six" class="knobs"></button>
  <br>
  <button id="seven" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="eight" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="nine" class="knobs"></button>
</div>
```

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Another thing: learn about [event delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/4642212). You don’t need nine distinct event listeners. You only need to bind a single one with an argument (e.g. `e`) to `#total` and check with `e.target` which knob has been clicked.

Comment: I add an alternative solution to your version and a little optimizations

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your if statement only runs once in the beginning. You need to turn it into a function and then call it after each event. Something like

```
function check() {
    if (one.style.backgroundColor == "red" && two.style.backgroundColor == "red" && three.style.backgroundColor == "red"){
    console.log("red wins");
    }
}
```

At the end of the event listener you would call it like so:

```
check();
```

(Like Xufox said above, you should really look into delegation so that this is more manageable and you don't have to repeat everything.)

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var three = document.getElementById("three");
var four = document.getElementById("four");
var five = document.getElementById("five");
var six = document.getElementById("six");
var seven = document.getElementById("seven");
var eight = document.getElementById("eight");
var nine = document.getElementById("nine");
```

1. You don't need to declare each of your buttons like this. You can optimize it using an array and a loop like `for` or `forEach`. Like this:

   ```
   var knobs = [
       'one', 
       'two', 
       'three', 
       'four', 
       'five', 
       'six', 
       'seven', 
       'eight', 
       'nine'
   ];

   knobs.forEach(function(id) {
     var element = document.getElementById(id);
     element.addEventListener('click', function() {
         ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. You are adding a listener to each button with `addEventListener`. This can be optimized as I mention in my point number 1. You get the button element with `var element = document.getElementById(id);` and the you cand add the listener in the same `forEach`.
3. I also used the same `forEach` to initialize my `board` array with `-1` for each element. This mean it is empty.
4. Now you need to add a method to verify is there is a winner after each click. In this code sample I used `verifyWinner(index);` and I passed the index of the button;
5. Also, in this line `one.style.backgroundColor == 'red'` only `==` is not enough so I suggest you to use `===` for compare `strings`.
6. The problem to use this method based on CSS is that **what happens if you click two or more times in the same knob?** The counter will increase and the knob will change the color from `red` to `yellow` for example. That is why I recommend you to use a `board` array to map the "game status".
7. Finally, I created a `board` as an array and I put `1` if is `red` and `2` if is `yellow`. This will help you to simplify the verification process.

Here is the code sample. Happy coding.
**Note**: I reduced the knob size for better visualization in the snippet runner.

```js
var knobs = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var board = [];

var isRed = true;
var isEndGame = false;
var counter = 0;
knobs.forEach(function(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  board.push(-1);
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var index = knobs.indexOf(id);
    if (!isEndGame && board[index] == -1) {
      if (isRed) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        board[index] = 1;
      } else {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        board[index] = 2;
      }
      verifyWinner(index);
      isRed = !isRed;
      counter++;
      //console.log(counter)
    }
    if (counter == 9) {
      isEndGame = true;
      console.log('End of game.');
    }
  });
});

function verifyWinner(index) {
  //logic for winning
  var player = isRed ? 1 : 2;

  switch (index) {
    case 0:
    case 2:
    case 6:
    case 8:
    case 4:
      verifyVertial(index);
      verifyHorizontal(index);
      verifyDiagonal(index);
      break;
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
      verifyVertial(index);
      verifyHorizontal(index);
      break;
  }
  if (isEndGame) {
    console.log((isRed ? 'Red' : 'Yellow') + ' has won.');
    console.log('End of game.');
  }
}

function verifyVertial(index) {
  //logic for winning
  if (!isEndGame) {
    var player = isRed ? 1 : 2;
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
      case 3:
      case 6:
        if (board[0] == player && board[3] == player && board[6] == player) {
          isEndGame = true;
        }
        break;
      case 1:
      case 4:
      case 7:
        if (board[1] == player && board[4] == player && board[7] == player) {
          isEndGame = true;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
      case 5:
      case 8: // edges
        if (board[2] == player && board[5] == player && board[8] == player) {
          isEndGame = true;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}

function verifyHorizontal(index) {
  //logic for winning
  if (!isEndGame) {
    var player = isRed ? 1 : 2;
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
      case 1:
      case 2: // edges
        if (board[0] == player && board[1] == player && board[2] == player) {
          isEndGame = true;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
      case 4:
      case 5:
        if (board[3] == player && board[4] == player && board[5] == player) {
          isEndGame = true;
        }
        break;
      case 6:
      case 7:
      case 8: // edges
        if (board[6] == player && board[7] == player && board[8] == player) {
          isEndGame = true;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}

function verifyDiagonal(index) {
  //logic for winning
  if (!isEndGame) {
    var player = isRed ? 1 : 2;
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
      case 4:
      case 8: // edges
        if (board[0] == player && board[4] == player && board[8] == player) {
          isEndGame = true;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
      case 4:
      case 6: // edges
        if (board[2] == player && board[4] == player && board[6] == player) {
          isEndGame = true;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.knobs {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.knobs:focus .clear:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#total {
  text-align: center;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div id="total">
  <button id="one" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="two" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="three" class="knobs"></button>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <button id="four" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="five" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="six" class="knobs"></button>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <button id="seven" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="eight" class="knobs"></button>
  <button id="nine" class="knobs"></button>
</div>
```